# How can I get the same CTRL+W behaviour from Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext4

In the past, ctrl+w used to close a single tab in Sublime Text (3), and if there were no tabs left open, it would close the text editor. How can I achieve the same behaviour in the updated Sublime Text? ST 4

EDIT: The setting I was looking for is `"close_windows_when_empty": true`

Comment: Sublime Text 4 behaves in the same way for me (Win 11) - how does it behave for you?

Comment: (On Windows 10 19043) 
CTRL+W closes each file, and once all files are closed, nothing happens

Comment: You mean, closes all of the files?

Comment: Update Sublime - I'm on Build 4113 (Help > About) on default settings and it closes each one separately.

Comment: EDIT: The setting I was looking for is "close_windows_when_empty": true
I am also on Build 4113. As I said, CTRL+W closes each file individually, but when there are no files open, it does nothing. What I would want is the behaviour as it was in Sublime Text 3 i.e. when there are no files open, CTRL+W closes Sublime Text.

Comment: Just added an answer - does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text 4 behaves for me as described - it closes all open files and when no files are open, it closes the editor.

However, you may have had your key bindings changed by a plugin/misconfiguration etc.

**Preferences** > **Key Bindings** will open up a file.

Ensure that for `ctrl+w`, the command is set to **`close`** not **`close_file`**.

Once changed, restart Sublime.

It should look like below:

```json
...
{ "keys": ["ctrl+w"], "command": "close" },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Really strange, for me this settings wasn't working:

```
"close_windows_when_empty": true
```

tried and tested everything else, finally I've completely uninstalled Sublime 4 and reinstalled it (using AppCleaner, deleted all configs etc).

Now:

```
"close_windows_when_empty": false
```

is really set to false, BUT **the last window is always closing "everything"**. exacty what I wanted. It works even the settings tells something else.
So: Reinstall possibly helps